# Correct setBasicFilter condition syntax

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to this programming language. Can someone help fix my syntax?
I am trying to combine this example:

```
     function setFilter() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

      var filterSettings = {};

      // The range of data on which you want to apply the filter.
      // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
      filterSettings.range = {
        sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
      };

      // Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter
      //         https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
      filterSettings.criteria = {};
      var columnIndex = 2;
      filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
        'hiddenValues': ["England", "France"]
      };

      var request = {
        "setBasicFilter": {
          "filter": filterSettings
        }
      };
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
    }
```

with this JSON representation:

```
    {
      "hiddenValues": [
        string
      ],
      "condition": {
        object(BooleanCondition)
      },
    }
```

to set this type of criteria (This is where I need help, I'm not sure what the object should be):

```
    //*original    'hiddenValues': ["England", "France"]
       'condition': {object(NOT_BLANK)}
```

I have been unable to find an example on the internet that uses the "condition" only "hiddenValues"
...Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are looking for is [object(BooleanCondition)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#BooleanCondition)

```
{
  "type": enum(ConditionType),
  "values": [{ object(ConditionValue) }],
}
```

Pick from the [enum(ConditionType)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#ConditionType) list that matches the filter condition you want. In the description it will let you know if you need to add the [object(ConditionValue)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#ConditionValue).

If you need one or more [ConditionValues](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#ConditionValue), add the object below to the `values[]` with **either** `"relativeDate" || "userEnteredValue"`

```
// object(ConditionValue) - Pick one
{
  "relativeDate": enum(RelativeDate),
  "userEnteredValue": string,
}
```

Place the [BooleanCondition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#BooleanCondition) inside the [object(FilterCriteria)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria) where you currently have `'condition': {object(NOT_BLANK)}`

```
// object(BooleanCondition) with condition "NOT_BLANK"
var condition_value = {
      "type": "NOT_BLANK"
    }

// New FilterCriteria object
filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
  'hiddenValues': ["England", "France"],
  'condition': condition_value
}
```

Comment: I no longer get an error with this change. However, I can't seem to get the desired result either. It seems every method I try to Filter the 2nd tab, it want's to do the 1st.  ...Even if the 2nd is the active tab. It also applies the filter to column C instead of column A (The darker filter icon). The filter is there, but with no conditions.

Comment: that is because it's `range` is `ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()`. Which is usually the 1st tab. You need to get the sheet you actually want. There are many ways to do that. [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()),  [getSheetsByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) etc. `ss.getSheets()[1].getSheetId()` will get the 2nd tab. Column A is at index 0 in this case

Comment: I just discovered that my edits were not being saved in the script. I'm not sure if it was because I had the sheet open on my phone and the computer at the same time or what. But, once I closed it all and reopened it, things started playing nice again.